# 'int' object has no attribute 'stack_list'

Tags: python

```
class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack_list = []


    def is_empty(self):
        if not self.stack_list:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def push(self,*item):
        print(len(item))
        for i in range(len(item)):
            self.stack_list.append(item[i])


ls = Stack.push(1,8,9,7,3)


<ipython-input-38-8ab5687194bd> in push(self, *item)
     14         print(len(item))
     15         for i in range(len(item)):
---> 16             self.stack_list.append(item[i])
     17 
     18
```

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'stack_list'

How can I push more than one item to the stack?

Comment: When you call method like this, the first argument is instance of class. You should do `ls = Stack()` and then `ls.push(1,8,9,7,3)`.

Answer (score 1):

You use a class with instance methods - hence you need an instance of the class:

```
my_stack = Stack()
my_stack.push(1,8,9,7,3)
```

should work.

You can shorten your push as well:

```
def push(self,*item): 
    self.stack_list.extend(item)
```

Comment: thanks that's work. first I have to initiliaze the object.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize an object of your class.

Try instead:

```
stack = Stack()
stack.push(1,8,9,7,3)
```